# How to keep same node when retry the failure job in Jenkins with naginator-plugin

Tags: jenkins

How to keep same node when retry failure  job in Jenkins ?

I have installed the Jenkins plugin naginator-plugin.

I have setup retry build  after failure in one Jenkins job. I want it could  keep the same node when it retry.
But I found it could not keep the same node  when the job build retry .
[image]

Comment: I think this plugin can't support this.